# Definition of Lebesgue integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

As I understand it, a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, \infty]$, (or more generally from any measure space $X$, is integrable (Lebesgue integrable) if $\int f d\mu$ is finite.  Why is it required to be finite.?  Shouldn't a function be called lebesgue integrable simply if the lebesgue integral exists?

Answer (score 2):

The actual definition is actually:

$$ f \quad \textrm{is integrable if} \int f^{+} \quad \textrm{and} \int f^{-} \quad \textrm{are finite}.$$

In this case we define $\int f$ to be their difference.

You are right though. Often people make the more general defition:

$$ f \quad \textrm{is integrable if at least one of} \int f^{+} ,\int f^{-} \quad \textrm{are finite}.$$

If $\int f^{+}$ is infinite and $\int f^{-}$  is finite, we define $\int f := \infty$.

If $\int f^{-}$ is infinite and $\int f^{+}$  is finite, we define $\int f := -\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to have linearity of the integral, that is, if $f, g$ are integrable, then $f+g$ is also integrable and $\int f+g=\int f+\int g$. This becomes problematic if $\int f = -\infty$ and $\int g = \infty$.